# Simple key => value array with QueryInterface

Tags: database, 8, entities

I'm looking at building a simple key => value array with a certain type of node I have in order to generate a select list in a form.

The thing is that I have thousands of nodes of this type and the page takes forever to load with the current code I have.

Is there a way to load only certain fields using the QueryInterface in order to cut on loading times? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'product')
  ->condition('status', 1)
;

$nids = $query->execute();

$nodeStorage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');

// Load multiple nodes
$nodes = $nodeStorage->loadMultiple($nids);

$list = array();

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $list[$node->field_code->value] = $node->title->value . ' (' . $node->field_code->value . ')';
}
```

Comment: entity query will give you only nids or whole nodes. So in order to get nid and title you have to use basic query. But if you have a lot of nodes I would suggest entity reference field instead.

Comment: Even if you optimize the query, adding thousands of options to a select is really a bad idea. Entity autocomplete fields are *really* easy to use in d8. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21TaxonomyIndexTid.php/function/TaxonomyIndexTid%3A%3AvalueForm/8 for example. just specifiy #target_type and use bundle selection settings to limit it to your node type. And as a result, you get the selected node. it does also validates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to do this is similar to what @Ivan Jaros mentions in the comment above. That is to use a Database service instead of EntityQuery service. There is a handy method on the query Statement, `fetchAllKeyed`, that I use all of the time in Drupal 7.

```
$database = \Drupal::service('database');
$query = $database->select('node', 'n');
$query->join('node_field_data', 'nfd', 'n.nid = n.nfd.nid');
$query
  ->fields('n', ['nid']),
  ->fields('nfd', ['title']) 
  ->condition('n.type', 'product')
  ->condition('nfd.status', 1)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAllKeyed();
```

Unfortunately this has drawbacks:

1. Multilingual - you need to do this manually in the query above.
2. Probably not going to work well with non-SQL drivers.
3. Might run into performance issues still because the data is not cached.